# How to fix? Color gets messed up when posing

Tags: modeling, rigging

[image][image]

I'm a blender noob, idk why this happens, how do I fix it?

Comment: Hello, hard to guess where it is messing up, maybe explain more in detail and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, here's the before picture, how do i share my file?

Comment: Use a platform like the one i've linked or workupload etc

Comment: You probably have overlapping faces, try to select all in Edit mode and M > Merge by Distance, if it's not the case, share your file

Comment: Here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j5SYgeZx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/j5SYgeZx/)

Comment: Merging it by distance turns all of it into one color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overlapping faces, sometimes 3 layers, for example if you select all the faces that have the skin material you'll see the whole body is skin colored, it is hidden behind the clothes:

[image]

I don't think that there's any easy way to fix it, the simplest is probably to keep a copy of your object as model, then select all in *Edit* mode, and merge: <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, then use the copy as reference to reassign the correct material:

[image]